# Aurelia Validation rule (bound to model) does not fire on subsequent activations of a view model

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to expand on the [Aurelia Contact Manager Tutorial](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/contact-manager-tutorial). Specifically: adding email validation to the contact-details.html view. I have followed the examples in the [Validation: Basics](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/validation/latest/validation-basics/1) documentation and on first pass it worked as expected: Launch application, select a contact from the contact-list module, then update the email to something invalid by removing the '@', then tab away. The validation rule fires and the error message is displayed.

However, if after launching the application I select a first contact followed by a second, hence triggering a second activation of the contact-details module, then the validation rule does not fire.

I have tried a validationController.reset() on activate of the contact-detail and while this will remove any 'old' error messages, the on blur validation will still not fire.

I have tried the two different methods of creating the validation controller (using NewInstance.of(ValidationController) vs ValidationControllerFactory) but both yield the same result.

If, after navigating to a second contact and 'breaking' the validation, I then refresh the browser and reload the page then the validation works again.  Until I choose another contact from the list which will then break it again.

I am new to Aurelia and JavaScript frameworks in general and I'm not sure if this is a bug or there is something extra required to handle re-routing to the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a good question. There are a couple of things that may be catching you out. I've created a Gist which includes the necessary file modifications to get this working:

https://gist.github.com/freshcutdevelopment/170c2386f243e7095e276811dab52299

**Gotchas**

Because the view-model you're using for validation is not the backing view-model for the `contact-detail.html` view file you'll need a separate class which you'll apply the validation rules to. Although it sounds like you've already nailed this part, I'll include it for completeness. You can create this class like so:

```js
export class Contact {
  email= '';
}
```

You can then apply the validation rules to this class as follows:

```js
  ValidationRules
  .ensure(a => a.email).required().email()
  .on(Contact);
```

The last possible missing puzzle piece here is that you'll need to hook into the screen activation life-cycle hook `deactivate()` and reset the validation context. This will force the `BootstrapValidationRenderer` to remove the validation styles from your view.

```js
  deactivate(){
    this.controller.reset();
  }
```

**Validation Workflow**

The steps are as follows:

1. Inject the controller
2. Add the [validation renderer](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/validation/latest/validation-basics/8) to the controller
3. Create the validation model (only needed if the model you want to validate is not the view-model that backs your view)
4. Apply the [validation rules](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/validation/latest/validation-basics/10) to the model
5. Determine when to re-set and execute the validation (in this case on the `deactivate` life-cycle hook.
6. Apply the [validation binding behavior](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/validation/latest/validation-basics/6) to the view

Comment: Thank you for your reply and code.  With a little modification I was able to get my code to work!  The only change I had to make to your code was to the ValidationRules definition: 'code' ValidationRules
.ensure('email').email().required()
.on(Contact); 'code'

Comment: Very nice, glad to here it! :D